# SilverStripe 3 Blog - Selecting categories based on sub-categories

Tags: php, blogs, silverstripe, categories

I have a SilverStripe blog that I have added subcategories to. The subcategories can belong to different categories. Is there a way to select a category automatically when a subcategory is selected?

So for example subcategory 1 belongs to category A and category B. That blog post needs to show in both those 2 categories when I select subcategory 1.

Is there a way to go about this?

EDIT:

I am just using the SilverStripe blog module and added in my own code for the subcategories so I can link the subcategories to the categories.

```
$gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
$gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkManager());
$gridfield = new GridField("BlogSubCategories", "BlogSubCategories", $this->BlogSubCategories(),$gridFieldConfig);
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $gridfield);
```

No problem with that. I am just unsure how to say "when I add a subcategory to a blogpost add the related categories as well."

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What did you try to do and what does not work? Please provide the code you are using.

Comment: I have added in the code and the explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silverstripe REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831602/silverstripe-rest-api)